# Log warnings into a table

Tags: mysql, logging

I found the following code on mysql forge site.

MySQL Proxy : An easy way to log all warnings and errors into a MySQL table.

http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=133

This may sound too basic, but from where do I start if I need this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-proxy-scripting.html) you have more details about MySQL proxy scripting.

What you need to do with the script you [linked](http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=133) is just run it on MySQL database and it will do all the magic for you. It's a complete server side solution so you don't have to worry about logging errors in your client application. MySQL will automatically run `read_query` function for every row returned and `read_query_result` for every set returned.

Comment: Unfortunately the provided link is dead. For more information, I had a similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415727/how-to-log-sql-errors-and-warnings-with-a-lua-script-on-mysql-proxy/17467651#17467651