# How to log SQL errors AND warnings with a Lua script on mysql-proxy

Tags: mysql, lua, mysql-proxy

For debug purposes, I want to log SQL errors and warnings messages returned by MySQL, and corresponding queries, at server-level.

I've found two useful Lua scripts :

https://github.com/koopa/mysql-proxy-log-error-queries/blob/master/mysql-proxy-log-error-queries.lua
https://github.com/patrickallaert/MySQL-Proxy-scripts-for-devs (debug.lua)

which allow to log errors with MySQL Proxy. But I'm still looking for a way to log warnings.
I'm not confident with mysql-proxy LUA-scripting. Can someone indicate me how to do this ?

This question : [Log warnings into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276144/log-warnings-into-a-table) seems to be close, but unfortunately the provided link is dead and I can not find the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally examined the subject in studying literature and developed the Lua script that suits me.

The script I mentioned first (https://github.com/koopa/mysql-proxy-log-error-queries/blob/master/mysql-proxy-log-error-queries.lua) was a good starting point, but :

- It only logs errors and not warnings. Originally it manages an 'error flag' which is set to true if the client's query returns an error. I changed that in order to log every query for which `SHOW WARNINGS` returns something (Errors, Warnings or Notes).
- It inserted errors log lines into a table. It could be nice but can be quite confusing for the client, because inserting the log line clears the messages shown by 'show warnings' query. There's probably a way to fix that, opening a new session or connexion... but I choosed to log events into a simple text file. Secondarily, the insert query in the original script can generate a syntax error because of the simple quotes `'` possibly contained in the error message or original query.

There is a point at which we must be careful when logging all warnings : all queries don't clear the warnings/notes queue. So `SHOW WARNINGS` can return a resultset generated by a previous query after a *non-warning-generating query*.
To fix that, I use a dirty method : after detecting a query, I inject a bad query for which I know it will generate an error message; after what I ignore this error message. It's a way to "clear" warnings and notes...

Answer (score 0):

You can download this script and specify while configuring MySQL-proxy.
Command line options are listed here:
[MySQL-proxy-configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-proxy-configuration.html)

Typical MySQL-proxy configuration will look like this in your case:

> $ mysql-proxy --proxy-backend-addresses=192.168.x.x:3305
>   --proxy-address=192.168.y.y:4045 --proxy-lua-script=mysql-proxy-log-error-queries.lua

I guess you might have to modify this script to connect to MySQL-proxy.

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew how to launch mysql-proxy My question was how to log warnings in a Lua script